# Implementation Types of Triangle with Java and JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I made **TypeofTriangle.java**

```
public class TypeofTriangle {

public static int triangle(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a<b && b<c && (a*a)+(b*b)>(c*c)) {
        System.out.println("Triangular Taper");
    } else if(a<b && b<c && (a*a)+(b*b)=(c*c)) {
            System.out.println("Right Triangle");
        } else if (a<b && b<c && (a*a)+(b*b)<(c*c)) {
            System.out.println("Blunt Triangle");}
    }
}
```

And I made for the class test **TypeofTriangleTest.java**

```
import junit.framework.*;

public class TypeofTriangleTest extends TestCase {
    public TypeofTriangleTest(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

public void testSimple() {
    assertEquals("Triangular Taper", TypeofTriangle.triangle(6,8,10));
    }
}
```

But when I run the class test, there's one error. it said

```
java:6: operator && cannot be applied to boolean,int
        } else if(a<b && b<c && (a*a)+(b*b)=(c*c)) {
```

So what I'm supposed to do? hmm and I'm confused about return statement in TypeofTriangle.java, because I wanna to return the result of System.out.println, how to make it works?

Comment: Did you mean to use `=` or `==`? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: I mean the result of (a*a)+(b*b) same with (c*c) @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Answer my question and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can correct it by modifying this as follows:

```
else if(a<b && b<c && ((a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c)))
```

To return something, I would change the type to string:

```
public class TypeofTriangle {

    public static String triangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a<b && b<c && (a*a)+(b*b)>(c*c)) {
            return "Triangular Taper";
        } else if(a<b && b<c && ((a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c))) {
            return  "Right Triangle";
        } else if (a<b && b<c && (a*a)+(b*b)<(c*c)) {
            return "Blunt Triangle";
        }   return "Not a triangle";
    }
}
```

Comment: okay it's done and it works thankyou hehe, one more question, any idea for variables to return statement? because when I compiled it, I forgot to declare the return statement, and what I wanna return is the result of System.out.println

Comment: @ulaaaan What are you trying to return?

Comment: I wanna to return the "Triangular Taper", "Right Triangle" or "Blunt Triangle". Depends on which condition that fulfilled.

Comment: @Richard Your code won't compile. You haven't an `else` case, only `else if` ....

Comment: @Mik378 You're right.  Copy/paste errors, the bane of coders everywhere! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

`b<c && (a*a)+(b*b)=(c*c)`  is equivalent to `b<c && c*c`  (assignment returning the result in Java)

Therefore compiler warns about the incompatible operand: `boolean` with `int`.

As @Richard wrote, replace the `=` by the equal operator: `==`, therefore returning a `boolean`.

By the way, you could refactor your code as this:

```
if(a<b && b<c) {
  if((a*a)+(b*b)>(c*c))
    return "Triangular Taper";
  else if((a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c))
    return "Right Triangle";
  return "Blunt Triangle"   //indeed, if it's not superior nor equal, it's surely inferior, explicit condition is useless.
}
return "my default value"  //or throws a relevant exception
```

Comment: `int` doesn't make sense regarding your values, change the return type to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public class TypeofTriangle 
{

    public static String triangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a<b && b<c && ((a*a)+(b*b))>(c*c)) {
            return "Triangular Taper";
        } else if(a<b && b<c && ((a*a)+(b*b))==(c*c)) {
            return "Right Triangle";
        } else if (a<b && b<c && ((a*a)+(b*b))<(c*c)) {
            return "Blunt Triangle";
        }
        return "no triangle";
    }
}
```

For comparison use == and not just =. Also instead of writing (a*a)+(b*b) wrap it in parenthesis ((a*a)+(b*b)).

Answer (score 1):

You should have got a compilation error in your TypeofTriangle class. incompatible operand: boolean with int. Basically you are trying to compare integer and boolean. Use == operator instead of = operator.